# How to validate jsonb array of objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model, called `Order`, to which I'd like to add a new `jsonb` column called `status_updates`. This column will contain data of the following format:

```
status_updates = [{ status: 'success', created_at: <timestamp> }, { status: 'processing', created_at: <timestamp> }]
```

I would like to validate the `status` attribute of each `status_updates` element is one of the following: `success`, `canceled`, `processing`. Additionally, I'd like to validate that each element has a `created_at` timestamp.

How would you do that in Rails? Is it possible to do something similar to `enum` for the statuses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if I were you, I might consider creating an `OrderStatus` model, something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: order_statuses
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  status           :integer          default(0)
#  order_id         :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class OrderStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  validates :status, 
            presence: true,
            inclusion: { in: 0..2 }

  enum status: {
    processing:     0,
    success:        1,
    cancelled:      2,
  }

end
```

And then in `Order`, do something like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_statuses 
end
```

Now, every `OrderStatus` record will have a `created_at` value (assuming your `OrderStatus` is valid and saved). And, `status` will be validated as one of the values in the `enum`. As written, `status` will default to `processing` - which you may or may not want.